# How to prevent bootstrap css classes from being overridden by custom css theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, umbraco7

I am working on Umbraco with the Fanoe starter kit. For one of the rows, I use class of "dark". Inside this row, I add a link with classes "btn btn-primary".

Now the bootstrap button font for instance is being overridden by whatever has been defined in the "dark" class.

How to use bootstrap css classes without being overridden by any other css defined?

One thing I could think of is to grab all css related classes from bootstrap and add "!important", but is this the right way to do?

Thanks

Comment: Ultimately using `!important` will get the job done, You'd have to figure the order in which everything is executing if you wish to define classes to perform a normal css override.

Comment: Since order and specificity matters, it would help if you post the rules and their order